# Problem using FBO: Only first pass renders. A possible problem at setting render target back?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

I have a huge problem with using FBO.

I have a multi-pass display using FBOs and multitexturing. Everything seems to work fine until the end of first execution of display.

I set the render target back to screen using glBindFrameBufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0) at the end of my display function but the passes after that do not take effect. The screen seems to freeze..

What might be the cause? Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the

```
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

before binding the FBO, and

```
glPopAttrib();
```

after you release it.